# Printing first N natural numbers function not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

Why is this python code returning `1` for any input?

```
#code for a function which prints the first n natural numbers
n = raw_input("Enter n")
n = int(n)
def printint(p):
  for i in range(1 , n+1):
    return i 
print printint(n)
```

Comment: Because you have a return in your for loop and it will return the first `i` in the loop that it encounters, which in this case it's 1, the first item in your range.

Comment: yes `return` *terminates* the function

Comment: Why ? Isn't it supposed to return all the i's in the range ?

Comment: No, `return` alone exits the function and `return value` exits and returns a value. It also terminates all enclosing loops however deeply nested that might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to print the numbers, not to return them:

```
def printint(p):
  for i in range(1 , p+1):
    print i
```

Then just call the function alone, since it is printing inside:

```
printint(n)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/FastAstonishingDatalogs)

EDIT: Your final code should look like this:

```
def printint(p):
  for i in range(1 , p+1):
    print i
n = int(raw_input("Enter n"))
printint(n)
```

Comment: This is giving blank output after entering n.

Comment: what is the value for your `n`?

Comment: there where a bug, it should be `p` not `n` inside the function

Comment: still getting blank output. to be clear, i should still retain the above two lines for getting input, right ?

Comment: this is the final code  : n = raw_input("Enter n")
    n = int(n)
    def printint(p):
      for i in range(1 , n+1):
        print i
        printint(p)

Comment: @DeveshLohumi, I updated the example and the answer, example is working...

Comment: Yes, Why/Is it wrong to take the input before defining the function ?

Comment: @DeveshLohumi, it is not wrong, but in my opinion is better to separate definitions from executions, it would be even better if you are using this in a script to use an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block